# 'thought it was" or "thought it would"

Tags: difference, tense, past-tense

> I **thought it was** cheaper to send it airmail but in fact when the postman told me the price  it was  very expensive.

> I **thought it would be** cheaper to send it airmail but I was wrong it was very expensive.

Are both sentences correct? In this context I think there is not much difference only that "would" mean I was not sure

Comment: Both are syntactically fine, and mean the same thing. I can't see any justification for supposing that the "would" version implies I didn't hold that mistaken belief as strongly as the "was" version. If you wanted the implication of not holding the belief strongly), you could say something like *I thought [perhaps] it **might** be cheaper...*

Comment: **I thought it would be cheaper** has the sense "I had expected to discover that the airmail price was cheaper" - so the basic meaning is the same.